# Using Constructors to compare/calc user input

Tags: c++, class, constructor

In my program, i am supposed to accept 2 money values (creating 2 instances of class/constructor) but i'm also supposed to compare them. I'm not sure how to compare them, or which constructor to use (i have 3 overloading constructors).
the first if statements commented out are how I thought of comparing values, but it kept reprinting displayMoney() the same amount of times I wrote it. The 2nd if statements are of how i thought the program would choose the constructor to use based on user input. Sorry new to using constructors/oveloading, and its confusing.

Heres my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class money
{
private:
    int dollars;
    int cents;
public:
    money();
    money(int str);
    money(int str1, int str2);
    double displayMoney();
};

money::money()
{
    dollars = 0;
    cents = 0;
}
money::money(int str)
{
    dollars = str;
    cents = 0;
}
money::money(int str1, int str2)
{
    dollars = str1;
    cents = str2;
}

double money::displayMoney()
{
   double total = dollars + cents/(double)100;
   cout << "$" << total << endl;
   return total;
}




int main()
{

    int input11, input12, input21, input22;

    money c;

    cout << "Enter 2 money values: "<< endl;
    cout << "\n Dollars 1: ";
    cin >> input11;
    cout << " Cents 1: ";
    cin >> input12;

    cout << "\n Dollars 2: ";
    cin >> input21;
    cout << " Cents 2: ";
    cin >> input22;

    money x(input11, input12);
    money y(input21, input22);

  /*if(x.displayMoney() > y.displayMoney())
   {
        cout << "\n $" << x.displayMoney() << " is greater than " << "$" <<    y.displayMoney() << endl;
   }
   else if(x.displayMoney() < y.displayMoney())
   {
        cout << "\n $" << y.displayMoney() << " is greater than " << "$" << x.displayMoney() << endl;
   }
   else
   {
       cout << "\n $" << x.displayMoney() << " is equal to " << "$" << y.displayMoney() << endl;
   }*/


 /*if (input1 > 0 && input2 > 0)
   {
       money x(input1, input2);
       x.displayMoney();
   }
   else if (input2 <= 0 && input1 > 0)
   {
       money x(input1);
       x.displayMoney();
   }
   else
   {
       money x;
       x.displayMoney();
   }*/

   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: look up operator overloading.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices.  Either overload one or more comparison operators, or provide a method that returns a single comparable value (total cents).

**Option 1:**

```
class money {
  //...

  public:
    bool operator< ( const money & b ) const {
        return dollars < b.dollars || dollars == b.dollars && cents < b.cents;
    }
};
```

You can define `operator>` and `operator==` in a similar way, or you can derive them from `operator<`:

```
bool operator> ( const money & a, const money & b ) { return b < a; }
bool operator== ( const money & a, const money & b ) { return !(a < b || b < a); }
```

**Option 2:**

```
class money {
  //...

  public:
      int totalCents() const { return dollars * 100 + cents; }
};
```

Now you can compare the actual amount without operator overloading, since you have reduced a "money" to a single built-in value.